# How can we render the values of Multiple JSON files into a tabular format in React JS?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, tabular

I have a requirement to show a tabular format of the data which is store in multiple JSON files. Can someone please guide me on how I can proceed?

Comment: Can you please give an example of your JSON data and how do you like to display it? Are the JSON files identical or with different keys?

Comment: The scope of your question is far too broad and is basically asking for a tutorial. This isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Break this down into smaller steps and show us what you are trying and what is or isn't working on those specific steps. See [ask] and [mre]. WHen you post actual code along with a specific problem people are more than willing to help